# Get values of columns of a file with tabs and newlines separating them read via bash script to an array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, sh

Hello I have been trying to get the numbers in the columns of a file for two days by reading a file via a bash script. Here is the file sample.txt

```
       1    1   1   1   1
       9    3   4   5   5
       6    7   8   9   7
       3    6   8   9   1
       3    4   2   1   4
       6    4   4   7   7
```

By column I mean i.e the first column is

```
        1
        9
        6
        3
        3
        6
```

I need to have the column elements each be in a given array col1 or col2 etc so that I can manipulate the values further.

Here's what I have done so far using while loop I have read the contents of the file assigning them each line to an array.
If I set IFS=$'\n'

```
      while read -a line
      do
         IFS=$'\n'
         #I can get the whole column 1 with this
         echo ${line[0]}
         #for column 2 I can get it by this an the others too
         echo ${line[1]}
      done < sample.txt
```

Now that may seem good as i thought but since I want to calculate averages of the columns putting in another loop like a for loop becomes impossible since **${line[0]} has all the elements in column 1 but they are all as a single string** (i have tried to observe) that cannot be acted upon.

What would be the best way to get those elements be members of a given array and then compute the averages on them. help appreciated .

Comment: Does it really have to be bash? I mean builtins only?

Comment: Yes no externals like awk

Answer (score 1):

In bash I'd write

```
declare -A cols
n=0
while read -ra fields; do
    for ((i=0; i<${#fields[@]}; i++)); do
        cols[$i,$n]=${fields[i]}
        ((n[i]++))
    done
done < sample.txt
```

`read -a` reads the fields of the line into the named array.
I'm using `cols` as an associative array to fake a multi-dimensional array. That's way easier to deal with than using a dynamic variable name:

```
eval "column${i}[$n]=\${fields[$i]}"
```

Comment: Hello I have tried this solution and my shell is complaining about n[i]++ .  is it legal?

Comment: used let n[i]++ and solved it now the output is a bit clear I have echoed it it looks like  column 0[1]=1
column 1[1]=1
column 2[1]=1
column 3[1]=1
column 4[1]=1
column 0[2]=9
column 1[2]=3
column 2[2]=4
column 3[2]=5
column 4[2]=5     and the rest follows .

Comment: Sorry, missed the parentheses.